# rails mysql server error "could not find gem"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

When I try to run "rails server" on a new project it returns

```
Could not find gem 'mysql2 (>= 0) X86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. 
Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.
```

I ran 'bundle install' but I'm getting the same error.

I already had mysql installed from the xampp package, but my friend helped me install rails so I'm not sure how he configured it. I use Windows Vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue a while back setting up a RoR dev environment on a windows machine.  Had to copy the dll to the ruby/bin folder.  See the thread from ruby-forum...
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/150580

Answer (score 2):

Try `gem install mysql2`. It should then work.

Comment: `gem install mysql2`. i added to my answer.

Comment: When I try to run "rails server" it says "This application has failed to start because LIBMYSQL.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem." Does that mean it's trying to access mysql2 which I never installed or that something's off with the configuration?

Comment: I found this : http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/libmysql-dll-not-found-missing-error.htm

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. For me, I needed to remove the old Gemfile.lock and allow it be re-generated by running bundle update *after* I added the same version of mysql to the Gemfile that I had installed via "gem install mysql".

This may or may not be the issue you were running in to, but it appears this error message -> "Could not find gem 'mysql'" can be caused for this reason as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but when trying to `gem install mysql2`, it would give me a `can't find header files for ruby at ...` error message.

Running this fixed the issue for me: `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`